# Android Studio - adding library

Tags: android, android-studio

My problem is adding a library to my project in Android Studio. In module dependencies I'm gettin this weird thing. Any help will be appreciated.
Here is the pic:
[image: modules window]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android libraries are usually come as links to sources not as jars or some other type.
Take a look at the image. Do you see that there are actually 2 build.gradle files? what you need is the (Module:app) gradle build file select that and paste the link in the dependencies part in the bottom of that file just like what i have done , then Android Studio will ask you to sync the file. Do it. It will download the dependency from your link provided and integrate with the project
Hope this helps..[image: Android Studio build.gradle]